# Which coordinate system is the best for a distances from whole USA?

Tags: coordinate-system, united-states, epsg

I have about 100 cities all over the USA and want to calculate some distances. According to that I want use one coordinate projection and need to know which one is the best so I can get the most accurate results. I have compared the results using NAD83 for Texas and NAD 83 for Washington for a same data and the results are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate distances then you should use an Equidistant projection that best covers the USA. [USA Contiguous Equidistant Conic](http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/usa-contiguous-equidistant-conic/) would likely be an appropriate choice.

Comment: Is "USA_Contigous_Alberts_Equal_Area_Conic" a good choice?

Comment: Given your goal to calculate distances, no. Most projections preserve one of three properties: distance, area or angles, at the expense of the other two. The one you just suggested would ensure that areas of a feature anywhere on the map are conserved, but not distance. I suggest you read about map projections, how they work and how they distort some properties of features to maintain accuracy of another: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/map-projections/about-map-projections.htm

Comment: Good. So,  according to this my best choice is a ESRI: 102005 because I want to calculate distances?

Comment: To be more specific: It is a good choice because you want to calculate distances in the USA.

Comment: Exactly. Excellent.

Comment: Be careful with asserting the fitness of an equidistant projection for random distance calculations. The equal distance property only holds for one or two points to any other point. For many applications, an equal area projection may be better suited for general "as the bird flies" distance, and UTM for distance within 4-6 degrees. Calculating spheroidal distance is more expensive but far more accurate.

Answer (score 5):

Your best workflow may depend on whether you want "as the crow flies" distances or "via road" distances. For the latter, you would need to have a line data layer. For the "as the crow flies", you should look at tools that support a "geodesic" option. If it supports a geodesic option, that will give the shortest distances on the ellipsoid surface. The calculations won't take elevation into account though.

As Vince points out in comments, equidistant projections have very limited equidistant lines. For a conic or cylindrical equidistant projection, the standard parallels and all meridians only are equidistant.

Comment: [Comic projection](https://xkcd.com/977/) :D

Comment: @csk Good catch

Answer (score 0):

A simpler option might be not to use a projection and compute distances directly from geographical coordinates using [the Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: Single sentence answers are automatically flagged for poor quality, so please add some details to flesh out this answer some more. Haversine is spherical, not spheroidal, so this answer needs a caveat about accuracy.

Comment: Not only is Haversine not accurate enough for some use cases (since it assumes a sphere), but I would argue that it's not even the "simpler option".  If you're using a formula, that means you're coding, and any legitmate GIS software can project two  points into an appropriate spatial reference with just two lines of code.  If you're needing to do millions of these measurements fast, Haversine may be faster than using a projected coordinate system, but at that point you decide if you want it fast or if you want it right.