Choosing projection when working state by state in USA
I’m doing a project where I am have the location of tons of monitoring stations across the continental US. I have to calculate their distances from the centroid of census tracts for every state.
So I’ve hit a bit of a roadblock. Since I’m going state by state I essentially have 50 different maps (not sure if I should just put them into 1 but I want my measurements to be accurate and minimize distortion so I’m separating them) I don’t know what projected coordinate system to use. With UTM zones and cartesian planes, there’s often multiple for each state, and the data doesn’t really cluster to one specific zone.
I’m fairly new to GIS and for the most part, I just use NAD83 projections, but I want to make sure this data is accurate.
Any thoughts?

Each state will have at least one state projection that you should use

And what projection would that be? When I look on ArcGIS Pro under states (Alabama for example) there’s an East and West.

well in that case you use one in the east of the state and the other in the west. It really depends on how many mm of error you can accept in your measurements

gotcha, so using the state projections (cartesian planes) would probably be my best bet over any other projection like UTM zones? there are states like iowa that almost entirely in one UTM zone, so would that just be more accurate for that case? (though i’m mostly worried about big states like california or texas as there is the largest chance for distortion)

See here for a more in-depth discussion of the problem.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301282/which-coordinate-system-is-the-best-for-a-distances-from-whole-usa
